# Linq Grouping items by property

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to group an object by one property (State). The end goal is to have a list. And within each list is an object consisting of two properties. I have data that looks like the following...

```
State      Name        ID
CA         John        12
CA         Kevin       13
CA         Joe         14
AZ         Sally       15754
AZ         Stuart      1263
TN         Sam         1211
```

How would one go about using linq to make this a list of object 'People' consisting of a person's name and ID grouped by state? This is what I've tried...but it's not working

```
var result = from groupOne in dataset
             group groupOne by OneGroup.State into g
             select new People() { People = g.ToList() }.ToList();
```

Comment: *it's not working* isn't particularly helpful. What errors are you getting and what does the `People` class look like?

Comment: and what is OneGroup?

Comment: `new People() { People = g.ToList() }` can't be legal, because a member can't have the same name as its enclosing type... (well, actually it's possible, if the People property is declared in a base class, but it seems unlikely...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you grouping by `OneGroup.State`, when `OneGroup` is not a part of the query?

That one should do the trick:

```
var result = from groupOne in dataset
             group groupOne by groupOne.State into g
             select new {
                 State = g.Key,
                 People = g.Select(x => new { x.Name, x.ID })
             };
```

It returns anonymous types, but you can easily change it to return your class objects if you need.